# Complex mysql search query, 'boolean and' search of keyword on mysql string

Tags: mysql

Well I needed to implement some search parameters on my applications, and could not come up with any better solution so i hope you guys could help me, my prob goes something like this->

i have a table with following columns,
id,question

now i am supposed to search keywords, with various criterias, such as->

1. If i search keyword "heart disease" the returned questions should contain both words "heart" and "disease"
2. Sentence like " We have a heartly disease" are returned because "heartly" contains "heart", but sentence like "We have a fooheart disease" won't be returned cause "foo" is before "heart" and that isn't acceptable according to the criteria given. But anything following "heart" or "disease" is acceptable.

Well these were the criterias given, I know my english isn't that impressive and haven't been able to explain my problem properly. But i do hope for a solution!! Thanks!!

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Looks like you forgot the rest of your post.

Comment: sorry posted it before completion!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably would be better off with a full text search engine like Lucene, but you can do it in mysql.  You would just have to build up the search criteria based on the number of words.  For many cases, this would be an incredibly inefficient query.

something like

```
select * from table
 where text like '% heart%' and text like '% disease%'
```

[Link to SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/35c16/3)

should work.

Note that this isn't necessarily the full solution.  The following value wouldn't be returned, because there would be no space before diseases or heart.

```
Diseases are bad.Hearts are very susceptible.
```

The problem, of course, is that you are going to have to start building up a lot of special cases.  To address the comments, and the example I showed, you would have to add in rules like:

```
select * from terms
 where (terms like '% heart%' or terms like 'heart%' or terms like '%.Heart%')
     and (terms like '% disease%' or terms like 'disease%' or terms like '%.disease%')
```

[Link to more advanced case](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/206b4/6)

You could also do this with some sort of regular expression.  This would handle the cases that you've brought up.

```
select * from terms
 where (terms like 'heart%' or terms REGEXP '[ |\.]heart')
  and (terms like 'disease%' or terms  REGEXP '[ |\.]disease')
```

[Example with regular expressions](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/206b4/18)

Comment: Well, i tried that but the prob is this only works for questions which don't start with words "heart" and "disease", for e.g "heart disease is bad" won't be returned. Thank for the reply though !!

Comment: what i have done myself is something like this ---->>> http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/35c16/4 , i know its wrong, but hope to improve it

Comment: its bad that i can't rep+ u :D being new and all, i will work around your query, thank you again